# Init error on loading CKEditor 4.5.10

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I changed the CKEditor from version 4.5.9 to 4.5.10. And now I get an error during initialization (Chrome Browser 51):

```
Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers[a.type] is not a constructor (ckeditor.js:462)
```

Do I need to change the configuration after this update?

Comment: hi ! can you please share your problem in Jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure how to insert a custom build with own plugins of CKEditor in JSFiddle. How can I handle this? Is the stack trace of the console helpful?

Comment: If you have created custom plugins, then you should look at them. Remove them and test CKEditor without those extra plugins, then start adding them one by one unless the stack trace might guide you faster to find out the culprit.

Comment: I have found that the problem exists when styling widgets:
`CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'default', [ { name: 'Round images', type: 'widget', widget: 'image', attributes: { 'class': 'round' } } ]);`
This was introduced in CKEditor 4.4: http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.4.0/widget-styles.html

If I disable this widget style, all works fine.